# git rev-list omit cherrypicked commits doesn't work

Tags: git, github, git-log, git-cherry-pick, git-rev-list

I'm using `git rev-list` (because that's what GitPython's `iter_commits` is running behind the scenes) to obtain the changes present in one branch and not the other.

I want to omit all of the commits that were cherry-picked into the older branch.

This is the tree of commits before cherry-pick:
[git log before cherry-pick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAIyx.png)

Now, I want to cherry-pick commit "6" into "release-6.6":

```
git checkout release-6.6
git cherry-pick 24e0f0c
```

This is the tree of commits after cherry-pick:
[git log after cherry-pick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYL0O.png)

Now I want to compare between branch `release-6.6` and branch `release-6.8` and get only commits `5,7,8`:

```
git rev-list release-6.6..release-6.8
```

And the output is 4 commits which are: `5,6,7,8`.

I even try:

```
git rev-list release-6.6..release-6.8 --cherry-pick
git rev-list release-6.6..release-6.8 --cherry-pick --right-only
git rev-list release-6.6..release-6.8 --cherry-pick --left-right
```

but none of them works.

What am I doing wrong? how can I get only commits `5,7,8`?

Thanks

Comment: To use `--left-right` or `--cherry-pick`, you *must* use the three-dot symmetric difference syntax, `release-6.6...release-6.8`

Comment: @torek, thanks! you solved my problem